# Mangled characters after distribution upgrade

Tags: gnome, upgrade, fonts

I recently upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 and now all my system characters are squares like:
[image]

I presume this is because some font I was using in 20.04 no longer exists, and the upgrade process wasn't smart enough to revert it to something that worked.

Sure enough, if I open Gnome Tweaks, it displays a warning symbol next to the "Shell" option under the Appearance tab. However, it doesn't give me any option to change it.

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you try changing the fonts? The *Font* section is right below *Appearance* in GNOME Tweaks (also seen in your screenshot).